# How should I implement a custom table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I am trying to change a cell in a tableview from generic to custom and have created a new tableview cell class.  However, I cannot get the cell to recognize the new custom cell.  Instead, it is still displaying the generic cell although I've changed the setting in storyboard to custom in the identify inspector and also changed the class for the tableview cell to the new custom one. I have also wired the elements in the cell in storyboard to the new custom class.

My understanding is the tableview VC knows which class to use from the `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and I have changed that too with the code below.  The project compiles but continues to show old generic cell. Can anyone see error or suggest what else to do?

```
#import "customCell.h"

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  customCell *cell = (customCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    Items *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit:**

A custom cell is created in the storyboard on top of tableview by dragging uielements.  Maybe this is an issue:

[image]

Style of cell is set to Custom:

[image]

Comment: did you gave the cell identifier as Cell in storyboard too ?

Comment: Yes it was previously Cell and it is still Cell. This seems to be how it is still displaying the generic cell.

Comment: can you post the screenshots of your custom cell xib ? IF you are not using  xib, how are you designing custom cell ?

Comment: There is nothing like custom in storyboard. It is either static cell or dynamic prototype. Could you please provide screenshots of how you set it as custom ?

Comment: Previously it was displaying both the generic cell and the new custom cell but showing the word "Label" for the custom cell instead of the actual data.  I managed to stop it from displaying the old data.  This was caused by there also being a configureCell method in the source file. So it is now displaying the words Label.

Comment: What I meant by Custom is the setting for style.  See screenshot.

Comment: please note that changing the style to custom, doesnt create a custom cell. It is for making changes to title, subtitle and their position on a table cell

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new UITableViewCell and enable the "create XIB file...".
Create your custom cell in the XIB and make it's custom class as your class you just created.

Then in `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` register the Nib: (it's in swift but I bet you can figure out the objective c parallel...)

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "YourUITableViewCellClass", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourCustomIdentifierFromTheCustomClass")
```

Then access your cell:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCustomIdentifierFromTheCustomClass")
```

and that's it.

Comment: You don't "need" to use a XIB, you can do it from Storyboard.

Comment: I guess you are right. It's just how I do it to keep the UITableViewController a bit cleaner in storyboard. Then when I need to access the cell's elements, using XIB is easier than calling view with tag :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a custom cell you have to do these things:

1. > Setup the labels, images etc on storyboard cell.
2. > Create a custom cell class (inheriting from
   >   UITableViewCell)(CustomCell.h & .m), CustomCell.h having all of the
   >   properties as iboutlet for labels, images etc. and synthesize them all
   >   in implementation.
3. > After creating this custom class go back to storyboard, select the
   >   custom cell, change its class to the CustomCell and give it some
   >   identifier like "MyCustomCell", then right click on the custom cell
   >   and connect the IBOutlets with labels etc.
4. > Now import CustomCell class in the class where you are implementing
   >   the UITableView and use the properties you defined in CustomCell
   >   class.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 

   {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

    CustomCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
        cell.myCustomLabel.text = @"My Text";
    return cell; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create custom cell in your main story board by drag the cell view.

create custom class for that prototype.

mention the class name in identifier inspector.

import that class to your view controller .h file.

and made connection of your custom from main story board to custom class.h file.

it works!.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell on your Storyboard, and enter the name of your class in this field.

When you dequeue it from the identifier, it'll be an instance of that class.

[image]

Comment: you need to show the scrrenshot of your custom cell. @user1904273

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something.  I am currently creating the custom cell in storyboard right on the tableview.  Do I have to create it somewhere else?

Comment: Ok.  Finally got it to work.  The cell was not getting the data.  I had to add line in above method  cell.item = item;

Answer (score 0):

Please note that each regular tableViewCell has a builtin and hidden UIImageView.

In Objective-C, you simply do this within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My awesome image"];
```

In Swift, it's pretty close.

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "My awesome image")
```