# Pass textfield to a label in a second view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, list

I am making a simple client invoice list using a tableView with custom labels in each row. at the top you click the plus sign. This takes you to a second page where you type in your clients name. you hit save and it should add it to the label in the first view controller. I cannot get this to work.

my tableview storyboard has the file called `ViewController.swift` - in it

```
import UIKit

var invoiceList = [""]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource   {
  
    @IBOutlet var clientTableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet var clientLabel: UILabel!
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
     return invoiceList.count
    }
    

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientItem", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        
        let ClientName = invoiceList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = [clientInput]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
        {
            invoiceList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            clientTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        clientTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

My second storyboard where you type in the text field. File is called `AddInvoiceItem.swift`. in it -

```
import UIKit

class AddInvoiceViewController: UIViewController  {

    var clientTextField:String!
    @IBOutlet var clientInput: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if clientInput.text != ""
        {
        invoiceList.append(clientInput.text!)
        clientInput.text = ""
            
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancelBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
    
}
```

My error keeps happening when I am trying to use the code line

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientItem", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        
        let ClientName = invoiceList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = [clientInput]
        
        return cell
    }
```

The `cell.textLabel?.text = [clientInput]`
I know this is wrong, but cannot figure it out!

[image]

Comment: have you tried clientInput.text!

Comment: I think you should try cell.textLabel?.text = ClientName

Comment: Are you sure data is being properly passed? I agree with @user1000 's second suggestion too, although the first one is wrong. This would be a good place I suppose to use delegation

Comment: I have tried what you guys suggested and the error is now gone. but now I keep getting the error  The clientLabel outlet from the ViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

Comment: I do see that I am not using the label clientLabel anywhere. This is the label that I am trying to get the clientInput text to

Comment: Is this label inside the cell of tableview?

Comment: If this label is inside the cell then you cannot connect the outlet to viewcontroller ,so you have to make a custom table view cell subclass and connect the outlet there, then use this cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: yes sir! I have the error gone but instead of putting it where the label was, it is putting it over top everything in the row. Is there a way I can send the file to you so it will make more sense when you see it?

Comment: I feel that you are right on that. I will have to do some digging to see how to pull that off

Comment: So what is the error you are facing now

Comment: its firing through now. I can add the text to the row, but it is still wrong! I will upload pics so you can see what it looks like

Comment: Kyle is not the name you want?is it wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to make custom cell in tableview?

Comment: no the name inputed fine, if you look at the picture the cell above the name Kyle. you see bold type Client Name... that is where the name Kyle should be going. once I know how to do that I was going to do all other label fields. No I can't figure out how to make it a custom cell

Comment: Please check my answer and see if you can figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new cell class

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
     //Make your outlets here, connect the outlets from cell in your storyboard like ClientNameLabel



}
```

Please select the cell on your Storyboard, and enter the name of your class in this field. In your case it would be CustomCell

[image]

then in ViewController

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientItem", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let ClientName = invoiceList[indexPath.row]
        cell.ClientNameLabel.text = ClientName

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: May be this link is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999945/how-to-implement-custom-cell

Comment: for some weird reason it will not let me connect the labels into the custom class. I put the custom cell above the class ViewController

Comment: Please make a new file CustomCell.swift file and follow the instructions above

Comment: Oh man that worked. I had the CustomCell label on the wrong layer. I needed to move it up one layer! It works now! very much appreciate it!

Comment: Good work @Blue Moose, I would like to point out one more thing, you should name your variables like clientName, follow this camel-case notation , I see you are following it for some variables like clientInput but not for ClientName. Please follow good practices and happy coding. :)

Comment: Will do I appreciate your help and feed back... I am struggling to make the description follow on same cell. It instead goes to the next cell down. I will look more into that tomorrow!

Comment: I think this problem is with constraints that you set on the labels, you should check that out

Comment: it is pulling in the right data for the client name. Now when I added description field it throws it to a new cell in the client name placement. I must be doing the wrong let statement.  `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "clientItem", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        
        
        let clientName = invoiceList[indexPath.row]
        cell.clientNameLabel?.text = clientName
        
        
        let descriptionName = invoiceList[indexPath.row]
        cell.descriptionLabel?.text = descriptionName
        
        return cell`